# foreach format in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to print the foreach in the browser using PHP, but I'm trying to give a line break to each return of the foreacha, but they are all together, I tried to use several forms but it doesn't change anything, any tips?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$giftes = json_decode(file_get_contents("../gifts.json"),true);

$indexs = array_chunk(array_keys($giftes), 99)[0];
$t = array_chunk($giftes, 99);

$tt = sizeof($t);

$coluna = array_column($giftes, 'value');
$soma = array_sum($coluna);


foreach ($t[0] as $iduser => $value) {

    $codigo .= "\n<b>Codigo:</b> $indexs[$iduser]\n\n";
    $cliente .= "<b>Cliente: </b> {$value[client]}\n";
    $valor .= "<b>Valor: </b> {$value[value]}\n";
    $data .= "<b>Data: </b> {$value[date]}\n";

}

print("<b>✨REL</b> \n");

print("$codigo \n $cliente \n $valor \n $data");
```

Comment: Use `<br>` to make line breaks in HTML.

Comment: If you can't output as html use chr(13) > carriage return
`$codigo .= "\n<b>Codigo:</b> $indexs[$iduser]\n\n" . chr(13);`

Comment: Thx so much guys worked perfecty!!!